# C – Passing a variable amount of arguments to main

Tags: c, linux, arguments, program-entry-point

I’m not sure if this is the correct way to do this. See my code below.
I want to be able to pass a list of arguments to main, which would then get stored in another array.

So, I want to be about to start the program with at least 1 argument… or as many arguments as I like. I might set a max amount of arguments to 32.

Eg.

./foo 3

Or

./foo 3 56 12 34 56 111  2222 33

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int     numbersEntered[argc];


    if (argc <= 1){
            printf("Not enough arguments entered\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("Arg count  %i\n",argc-1);


    for (i=1;i<argc;i++)
            numbersEntered[i]=atoi(argv[i]);
    for (i=1;i<argc;i++)
            printf(" numbersEntered %i\n", numbersEntered[i]);
```

}

Comment: Looks okay to me, if your compiler supports variable-length arrays. Why are you worried that this might not be the correct way?

Comment: After writing the answer I'm puzzled, your program is already doing exactly what you want, what's the question? :-)

Comment: Why are you indexing numbersEntered from 1 instead of 0? You're leaving numbersEntered[0] uninitialised.

Comment: The code above does work (on a Raspberry Pi).   However I am trying to make sure that I am doing it correctly.  As I am using argc to specify the size of the array 'numbersEntered[argc]'... I have always read that you have to specify the array size when declaring it.

Comment: @Troy because `argv[0]` is just the program name; the first argument is `argv[1]`.

Comment: @SchighSchagh So? `numbersEntered[i-1]=atoi(argv[i]);` leaves no uninitialised first element or possibility of accidentally reading it. (The size of numbersEntered adjusted by -1 as well of course)

Comment: @Troy IMHO, having a bunch of `-1` array index/bounds adjustments all over the place is less elegant and *more* error prone.

Answer (score 2):

That is already the case, `argv` is an array of pointers, one pointer for each argument on the command line (plus two, actually, the first one is the name of the program, then the arguments, and then a terminating NULL-pointer).

Regarding the array, the problem is that traditional C requires a size that is known at compile time, you can't just use `argc`; that said, some compilers like GCC, and more recent C standards, do allow it.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are non-standard as of C90, a standard feature of the language as of C99, and an optional feature of the language as of C11.

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi.. how do I confirm the C standard I am using?

Comment: @Mwilliams03 If your compiler accepts the above program you are ok. Beyond that, you are probably using some kind of GCC which has traditionally supported variable-length arrays independent of the language standard.